# R - Returning # instead of text on an ifelse

Tags: r

I have 3 columns hometeam, awayteam, attacking team. I'm trying to create a 4th column, defending team that will return the team name of whichever team isn't attacking.

```
test <- test %>% mutate(dteam = ifelse(ateam == hometeam, hometeam, awayteam))
```

That works, but it's returning a # as the team identifier instead of the team name. Is there a way to get the team name instead of the # identifier?

Comment: Can you provide your data with `dput(test)`?

Comment: Check that your teams are stored as characters and not as factors.  You can do this with eg `str(test)`

Comment: It sounds as if `hometeam` and/or `awayteam` might be factors rather than character. Try `mutate(hometeam=as.character(hometeam))` first (and similarly for `awayteam`)

Comment: It was factors rather than character. Thank you.